# build fingerprint that seems abnormal? Says Denver global product

Tags: build, android-fingerprint-api

S2RES32.29-16-1-2 Denver global product. What is a Denver global product and should it be listed as the build fingerprint and what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

`denver` is the "product name" or "board name".  Maybe both?

Here are all the "properties" from my phone (`adb shell getprop`) which contain the string "denver".

```
[gsm.version.baseband]: [M4350_HI431_41.1123.01.83R DENVER_NA_CUST]
[ro.boot.hab.product]: [denver]
[ro.bootimage.build.fingerprint]: [motorola/denver_global/denver:11/S2RES32.29-16-1-2/b50654:user/release-keys]
[ro.build.description]: [denver_global-user 12 S2RES32.29-16-1-2 b50654-d6017a release-keys]
[ro.build.fingerprint]: [motorola/denver_global/denver:12/S2RES32.29-16-1-2/b50654-d6017a:user/release-keys]
[ro.build.flavor]: [denver_global-user]
[ro.build.product]: [denver]
[ro.build.version.base_os]: [motorola/denver_global/denver:12/S2RE32.29-16-1/9dfb5-5f3f83:user/release-keys]
[ro.odm.build.fingerprint]: [motorola/denver_global/denver:11/S2RES32.29-16-1-2/b50654:user/release-keys]
[ro.opa.device_model_id]: [motorola-denver]
[ro.product.board]: [denver]
[ro.product.build.fingerprint]: [motorola/denver_global/denver:12/S2RES32M.29-16-1-2/d6017a:user/release-keys]
[ro.product.device]: [denver]
[ro.product.name]: [denver_global]
[ro.product.odm.device]: [denver]
[ro.product.odm.name]: [denver_global]
[ro.product.product.name]: [denver_global]
[ro.product.system.device]: [denver]
[ro.product.system.name]: [denver_global]
[ro.product.system_ext.device]: [denver]
[ro.product.system_ext.name]: [denver_global]
[ro.product.vendor.device]: [denver]
[ro.product.vendor.name]: [denver_global]
[ro.system.build.fingerprint]: [motorola/denver_global/denver:12/S2RES32M.29-16-1-2/d6017a:user/release-keys]
[ro.system_ext.build.fingerprint]: [motorola/denver_global/denver:12/S2RES32M.29-16-1-2/d6017a:user/release-keys]
[ro.vendor.build.fingerprint]: [motorola/denver_global/denver:11/S2RES32.29-16-1-2/b50654:user/release-keys]
[ro.vendor.hw.device]: [denver]
[vendor.ril.baseband.config.version]: [DENVER_NA_CUST]
```